# Reading a JSON file into Ansible and replacing or adding values to the imported data structure

Tags: json, variables, ansible

We have the configuration to 38 network devices in separate JSON files for each device.

We use an Ansible playbook, to lookup the relevant host and deliver its configuration using an F5 Deploy Module

```yaml
  vars:
    filename: "{{ansible_host}}.json"
    ffullpath: "/runner/project/do/net-prod/configs/{{filename}}"

  tasks:
  - name: Deploy the DO Code to the F5
    bigip_do_deploy:
      content: "{{ lookup('file', '{{ffullpath}}') }}"
      dry_run: "{{dryrun}}"
    register: result
```

The JSON configuration files have common elements across all of them.  For example, a list of four DNS servers.  Rather than have this repeated in all the configuration files, it would make more sense to have these in a separate common file which I can also import or substitute in the configuration file.  We also have other sensitive data in the JSON configuration files such as private RSI Keys.  I would also like to substitute these with a variable within Ansible.  I`m happy using variables in the playbooks, however, don't know have to achieve this within the JSON configuration files.

I have learned you cannot alter variables within Ansible and searched the net for solutions for some time.  Has anyone else done something similar?

I have tried various ways to manipulate variables within ansible.  Even loading the file into a DICT and trying to alter this with no luck.

Comment: You might want to use [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#ansible-builtin-template-module-template-a-file-out-to-a-target-host) to create/update the configuration files. Post [mre] and the expected result.

Comment: F5 claims in the description of [content](https://clouddocs.f5.com/products/orchestration/ansible/devel/f5_bigip/modules_2_0/bigip_do_deploy_module.html): *"For anything advanced or with formatting consider using the template lookup.
This can additionally be used for specifying application service configurations directly in YAML, **however that is not an encouraged practice** and, if used at all, should only be used for the absolute smallest of configurations to prevent your Playbooks from becoming too large."* I don't see a reason why *tempate* is **not an encouraged practice**.

Answer (score -1):

Q: ***"Read a JSON file and replace or add values to the data structure."***

---

Context: F5 documentation of the module [bigip_do_deploy](https://clouddocs.f5.com/products/orchestration/ansible/devel/f5_bigip/modules_2_0/bigip_do_deploy_module.html) suggests how to create content dynamically. However, instead of a feasible example of the *template* plugin, the [documentation](https://clouddocs.f5.com/products/orchestration/ansible/devel/f5_bigip/modules_2_0/bigip_do_deploy_module.html) says that the "template lookup plugin ... is not an encouraged practice ... should only be used for the absolute smallest of configurations" for the ridiculous reason "to prevent your Playbooks from becoming too large":

> **content**: Declaration to be configured on the system.
> This parameter is most often used along with the **file or template lookup plugins**. Refer to the examples section for correct usage.
> For anything advanced or with formatting consider using the template lookup. This can additionally be used for specifying application service configurations directly in YAML, however, that is **not an encouraged practice** and, if used at all, should only be used for the absolute smallest of configurations **to prevent your Playbooks from becoming too large**. If your content includes encrypted values (such as ciphertexts, passphrases, etc), the returned changed value will always be true. If you are using the to_nice_json filter, it will cause this module to fail because the purpose of that filter is to format the JSON to be human-readable and this process includes inserting "extra characters that break JSON validators.

---

A: What you try doesn't make any sense. You should use [templating](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_templating.html) even though the [documentation](https://clouddocs.f5.com/products/orchestration/ansible/devel/f5_bigip/modules_2_0/bigip_do_deploy_module.html) is saying that this is not an encouraged practice. [Templating](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_templating.html) is Ansible core functionality and should be used extensively whenever needed.

In this solution, the idea is to create the content in YAML and convert it to JSON as the last step. Technically, this means converting your files `{{ ansible_host }}.json` to templates `{{ ansible_host }}.yaml.j2` and use [template](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_lookup.html) lookup plugin

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: Deploy the DO Code to the F5
      bigip_do_deploy:
        content: '{{ lookup("template", template)|from_yaml|to_json }}'
        dry_run: "{{ dryrun }}"
      register: result
      vars:
        template: "{{ ansible_host }}.yaml.j2"
```

---

Notes:

- The type of the parameter [content](https://github.com/F5Networks/f5-ansible-bigip/blob/devel/ansible_collections/f5networks/f5_bigip/plugins/modules/bigip_do_deploy.py#L411) is [raw](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_program_flow_modules.html#argument-spec), i.e. the module *bigip_do_deploy* doesn't check whether the *content* is valid JSON or not.
- There are no [open issues with filter to_json](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+to_json), i.e. this filter should work as expected.
- See the feature request [#75962](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/75962) about the nested templates `{{ lookup('template', x) | from_yaml | to_json }}`. This solution suggests also this pipe.
- See the request [#73472](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/73472) to improve the documentation is in [backlog](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/73472#issuecomment-773382231).

---

In the first example, all components are explained and tested separately. In the second example, the same components are used to create the content on the fly and restrict the scope of sensitive data to a single task. The last example shows how to use multiple templates with multiple hosts and network devices. The examples don't provide valid configurations of the network devices. The goal is to show how to use templates with multiple sources of variables(group_vars, host_vars, play vars, task vars, vault files, ...).

**Example 1. Create YAML configuration files**

There are many options for [setup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/tips_tricks/sample_setup.html#sample-ansible-setup) Ansible. For example, let's create the below simple project for testing

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── files
├── group_vars
│   └── all
│       ├── net_dev_common.yml
│       └── net_dev_vault.yml
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
└── templates
    └── net_dev.yaml.j2
```

```ini
shell> cat ansible.cfg 
[defaults]
gathering = explicit
collections_path = $HOME/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/
inventory = $PWD/hosts
roles_path = $PWD/roles
retry_files_enabled = false
stdout_callback = yaml
```

Create common variables in *group_vars/all*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/net_dev_common.yml 
nd_dns_common: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

Create common vault variables in *group_vars/all*

```yaml
shell> cat group_vars/all/net_dev_vault.yml 
nd_passwd:
  nd1: passwd_for_nd1
  nd2: passwd_for_nd2
  nd3: passwd_for_nd3
```

---

[Encrypt](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/vault_guide/index.html) the file

```bash
shell> ansible-vault encrypt group_vars/all/net_dev_vault.yml 
Encryption successful
```

```bash
shell> cat group_vars/all/net_dev_vault.yml 
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
64373537613238313530376438313030643339383336313436363738343637646362626430396236
6135646536323563336539663364313966633066353231610a353365306338633338646261326661
31613062393934303331626238623836383862616338636564393630613865356333363239373731
6639383961356635640a663565336238613232346331663363616438666532646532663137333930
37323537306264633161326433646131353162323136343434316166616432313465626632643161
65616136386166336331306134613163353630306562333765373839623831356562313365306563
62333464303264646139323065663739633262663131666231646638643134666433653961366665
35626230316533323761
```

---

Create simple inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
localhost
```

Create a simple template for testing. For better readability, this template will create configuration files in YAML. All three parameters will be set dynamically

```yaml
shell> cat templates/net_dev.yaml.j2 
{% filter from_yaml %}
device: {{ item }}
dns: {{ nd_dns_common }}
passwd: {{ nd_passwd[item] }}
{% endfilter %}
```

For example, the below play

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    net_devs: [nd1, nd2, nd3]

  tasks:

    - name: Create configuration files
      copy:
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/files/{{ item }}.yaml"
        content: "{{ lookup('template', 'net_dev.yaml.j2')|to_nice_yaml }}"
      loop: "{{ net_devs }}"
      when: nd_init|d(false)|bool
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e nd_init=true

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [Create configuration files] *************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=nd1)
changed: [localhost] => (item=nd2)
changed: [localhost] => (item=nd3)
```

and creates the configuration files

```bash
shell> tree files/
files/
├── nd1.yaml
├── nd2.yaml
└── nd3.yaml

0 directories, 3 files
```

```yaml
shell> cat files/nd1.yaml 
device: nd1
dns:
- 8.8.8.8
- 8.8.4.4
passwd: passwd_for_nd1
```

```yaml
shell> cat files/nd2.yaml 
device: nd2
dns:
- 8.8.8.8
- 8.8.4.4
passwd: passwd_for_nd2
```

```yaml
shell> cat files/nd3.yaml 
device: nd3
dns:
- 8.8.8.8
- 8.8.4.4
passwd: passwd_for_nd3
```

Read the configuration files and convert the content to JSON

```yaml
    - name: Test configuration files
      command: echo '{{ content|to_json }}'
      loop: "{{ net_devs }}"
      register: out
      vars:
        file: "files/{{ item }}.yaml"
        content: "{{ lookup('file', file)|from_yaml }}"
      when: nd_deploy|d(false)|bool
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ out.results|map(attribute='stdout') }}"
      when: nd_deploy|d(false)|bool
```

The below debug task shows the filter [*to_json*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#formatting-data-yaml-and-json) converted the content of the file to [valid JSON](https://jsonlint.com/)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml -e nd_deploy=true

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [Create configuration files] *************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=nd1) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=nd2) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item=nd3) 
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Test configuration files] ***************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=nd1)
changed: [localhost] => (item=nd2)
changed: [localhost] => (item=nd3)

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - '{"device": "nd1", "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"], "passwd": "passwd_for_nd1"}'
  - '{"device": "nd2", "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"], "passwd": "passwd_for_nd2"}'
  - '{"device": "nd3", "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"], "passwd": "passwd_for_nd3"}'

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    net_devs: [nd1, nd2, nd3]

  tasks:

    - name: Create configuration files
      copy:
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/files/{{ item }}.yaml"
        content: "{{ lookup('template', 'net_dev.yaml.j2')|to_nice_yaml }}"
      loop: "{{ net_devs }}"
      when: nd_init|d(false)|bool

    - name: Test configuration files
      command: echo '{{ content|to_json }}'
      loop: "{{ net_devs }}"
      register: out
      vars:
        file: "files/{{ item }}.yaml"
        content: "{{ lookup('file', file)|from_yaml }}"
      when: nd_deploy|d(false)|bool
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ out.results|map(attribute='stdout') }}"
      when: nd_deploy|d(false)|bool
```

---

**Example 2. Create the content on the fly. Limit the scope of passwords to a single task.**

In the first example, the passwords, stored in the dictionary *nd_passwd*, are available in the scope of the whole play. The decrypted passwords are also stored in the files *files/nd*.yml*. In this project, we limit the scope of the variable *nd_passwd* to a single task and create the content on the fly

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── files
│   └── net_dev_vault.yml
├── group_vars
│   └── all
│       └── net_dev_common.yml
├── hosts
├── pb.yml
└── templates
    └── net_dev.yaml.j2
```

We moved the file *net_dev_vault.yml* from *group_vars/all* into the directory *files* and updated the playbook. Other files are the same as in the first example.

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    net_devs: [nd1, nd2, nd3]

  tasks:

    - name: Test configuration files
      command: echo '{{ content|to_json }}'
      loop: "{{ net_devs }}"
      register: out
      vars:
        content: "{{ lookup('template', 'net_dev.yaml.j2')|from_yaml }}"
        vault: "{{ lookup('file', 'net_dev_vault.yml')|from_yaml }}"
        nd_passwd: "{{ vault.nd_passwd }}"
        
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ out.results|map(attribute='stdout') }}"
```

The below debug task shows the lookup plugin *template* together with the filter *to_json* created the same valid JSON content on the fly

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [Test configuration files] ***************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=nd1)
changed: [localhost] => (item=nd2)
changed: [localhost] => (item=nd3)

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - '{"device": "nd1", "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"], "passwd": "passwd_for_nd1"}'
  - '{"device": "nd2", "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"], "passwd": "passwd_for_nd2"}'
  - '{"device": "nd3", "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"], "passwd": "passwd_for_nd3"}'

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

**Example 3. Multiple templates, multiple hosts, and multiple network devices**

In the below project

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── files
│   └── net_dev_vault.yml
├── group_vars
│   └── all
│       └── net_dev_common.yml
├── hosts
├── host_vars
│   ├── host1
│   │   └── nd_local.yml
│   └── host2
│       └── nd_local.yml
├── pb.yml
└── templates
    ├── net_dev_default.yaml.j2
    └── net_dev_extended.yaml.j2
```

Create two templates

```yaml
shell> cat templates/net_dev_default.yaml.j2 
{% filter from_yaml %}
device: {{ item }}
dns: {{ nd_dns_common }}
passwd: {{ nd_passwd[item] }}
{% endfilter %}
```

```yaml
shell> cat templates/net_dev_extended.yaml.j2 
{% filter from_yaml %}
device: {{ item }}
dns: {{ nd_dns_common }}
passwd: {{ nd_passwd[item] }}
is_clustered: {{ nd_clustered[item]|d(nd_clustered.default) }}  
is_license_expired: {{ nd_expired[item]|d(true) }}  
is_virtual: {{ nd_virtual[item]|d(false) }}  
{% endfilter %}
```

Put two hosts into the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[test]
host1 ansible_host=test_11
host2 ansible_host=test_13
```

and create *host_vars*

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host1/nd_local.yml 
net_devs: [nd1, nd2, nd3]
net_devs_templates:
  net_dev_default: [nd1]
  net_dev_extended: [nd2, nd3]
nd_clustered:
  default: false
  nd3: true
nd_expired:
  default: true
  nd3: false
nd_virtual:
  default: false
  nd3: true
```

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/host2/nd_local.yml 
net_devs: [nd1, nd2]
net_devs_templates:
  net_dev_default: [nd1]
  net_dev_extended: [nd2]
nd_clustered:
  default: false
  nd2: true
nd_expired:
  default: true
  nd2: false
nd_virtual:
  default: false
  nd2: true
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  tasks:

    - name: Test configuration files
      command: echo '{{ lookup("template", template)|from_yaml|to_json }}'
      loop: "{{ net_devs }}"
      register: out
      vars:
        template: "{{ net_devs_templates|dict2items|
                      selectattr('value', 'contains', item)|
                      map(attribute='key')|first }}.yaml.j2"
        vault: "{{ lookup('file', 'net_dev_vault.yml')|from_yaml }}"
        nd_passwd: "{{ vault.nd_passwd }}"
        
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ out.results|map(attribute='stdout') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [all] **************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Test configuration files] *****************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host1] => (item=nd1)
changed: [host2] => (item=nd1)
changed: [host2] => (item=nd2)
changed: [host1] => (item=nd2)
changed: [host1] => (item=nd3)

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  msg:
  - '{"device": "nd1", "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"], "passwd": "passwd_for_nd1"}'
  - '{"device": "nd2", "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"], "passwd": "passwd_for_nd2", "is_clustered": false, "is_license_expired": true, "is_virtual": false}'
  - '{"device": "nd3", "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"], "passwd": "passwd_for_nd3", "is_clustered": true, "is_license_expired": false, "is_virtual": true}'
ok: [host2] => 
  msg:
  - '{"device": "nd1", "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"], "passwd": "passwd_for_nd1"}'
  - '{"device": "nd2", "dns": ["8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"], "passwd": "passwd_for_nd2", "is_clustered": true, "is_license_expired": false, "is_virtual": true}'

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
host1: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host2: ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```